# Time Series(ts) in R doesn't take additional input variables

Tags: r, time-series

I am using the `ts` function for time series prediction in R. I tried it using SSAS(SQL) and it gives pretty good analysis for my data set. But when I try it in R it is like I can't pass many input variables.This is the function which I passed.

```
m<-ts(myt$amount, start = c(2010,1), end = c(2016,12),frequency = 12)
```

Can anyone tell me that where can I pass other input variables. As example, in my case I predict future amounts using monthly time data set. But I have other additional variables like `Sales_Cateory`, `Sales_subcategory`,etc which can be used as input variables.

I tried passing them as last parameters but didn't see any change for my results.

Comment: `zoo{}` is a better package for converting many variables to time series all at once. `ts` is limited in that regard

Comment: I will try it Thanks.

Comment: The function `ts` is only used to create time series objects. For prediction, you may want to use another functions, like `arima` for arima models or `arma` for arma models. These functions take as input a time series object.

Comment: when I plot the return values of ts function, it shows future prediction values in the graph. But they are very less accurate.

Comment: Try https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html for a list of time series forecast functions. For your current problem, `arima` have an option xreg for external regressor. (arima X models)

Comment: In the `arima` function, the `x` argument need a time series object. The `xreg` option allows to perform an arimaX model, arima with dependent variables.